# Play framework on Mac, performance issue

Tags: java, macos, playframework, osx-lion

I have installed Play framework on my Macbook pro. Play 1.2.4 on the latest 10.7.3.
I have 8 GB memory and i7 Quad core cpu (shows 8 cores).

This is all extremely cool and I am having fun coding in play. But then I just wanted to see what a performance I should be getting in production, so I changed the application config like this :

```
prod.application.mode=prod
```

My application class only has 1 method

```
public static void index() {
    String theman = "You are the man";
    render(theman);
}
```

and my application template for index is this :

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Home' /}

The man is ${theman}
```

Thats all.

When I run apache benchmark on this like :

ab -n 1 -c 1 http://localhost:9000/

I get good numbers, but if I got to -n 10 everything just hangs and my computer goes to 100% load on 1 core and just stays there for ever.

I used to get HEAP errors but I set this as an environmental variable :

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms800m -Xmx1500m"
```

And now I no longer get any errors, anywhere.

My co-worker tried my app which I tarred and gzipped before sending over, he can easily do -n 10000 -c 1000 an dit just runs and finished in no time at all, almost instantaniously.

So my question is, do I have to set any other system variables or what do I need to do to make my Play app run on my mac ?

Just to clear things, my mac is totally up to date by today, everything is 99% as it came from the factory, probably closer to 100%, except that I do have xcode and such installed.

My java is :

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11D50b)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)

uname -sa

Darwin xxx.local 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Are you going to deploy the app on your macbook? If not, why is performance on the OS relevant? Also, did you try to profile the app to find the bottleneck?

Comment: I have not tried to profile the app. I have not found any Mac hosting company and I am not looking for one either, so no I will not deploy on the Mac, but I want everything to work and I want to show people statistics, and how well it handles under load. So in my opinion, this is quite trivial to get right. I have no idea on what parameters so set and environment variables to use

Comment: I think you mean your quad (4) core i7 shows 8 cpus.

Comment: Two things: (1) you changed config, BUT did you start app in prod mode (ie: play run --%prod )? (2) ab has some bugs in Lion, try to google: apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (54)

Comment: Yes, it was in production mode. I tried more than a few times, but java always crashed badly, every time, I had to kill the java process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this problem.

The Apache Benchmark utility that comes with Mac OS X Lion has a strange bug that manifests itself with Play 2.0 but not Play 1.2.x. On my machine, it duplicates each request, sometimes up to a dozen times.

You can verify this by running a single test and then seeing how many hits are in your log files.

More recent versions of ab do not have this problem. You can [build it yourself](https://gist.github.com/1430691) or download a [binary that someone made](https://github.com/radiospiel/ApacheBench-Lion).

Comment: This is verified. By just doing a simple test